# How to make random pick python differently?

Tags: python

I want to make a bot that sending 3 emoji but its different emoji , but when im running it , the bot took one emoji and sending a same 3 emoji, how do i make it take the different 3 emoji?

```
list  = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
text = random.choice(list)
```

that the code

edit : can you tell me whats wrong in this one?

```
import discord
import requests
import random
import sys

token = sys.argv[1]
chan = sys.argv[2]
client = discord.Client()
list = requests.get('emoji.txt').text.split("\n")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    txtchan = client.get_channel(int(chan))
    while not client.is_closed():
        message = ''
        for x in range(5):
            message += random.choice(list)
        await txtchan.send(message)
client.run(token, bot=False)
```

Comment: sorry if my question look ridicolous to you

Comment: Here is a great answer to the more generic question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45969227/769486

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587387/python-picking-an-element-without-replacement

Comment: @LimitedBrainCells I think the main issue here may actually be a misunderstanding on how variables work.  When you call `random.choice()` it gives a single result and is fixed.  You would need to call the function additional times to get new random results.  EDIT: your edit corrected this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example like that:

```
list  = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
text = set() #~ Set contains only unique elements
while len(text) < 3:
    text.add(random.choice(list))
```

This should after while, always hold 3 elements, but it can take longer if pseudorandom will 'randomly' pick 999 times that same emoji, almost impossible, but there is a chance.

Another way, more constant in time is shuffle:

```
list  = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
random.shuffle(list)
text = list[:3]
```

But that without makeing copy, always shuffle your first `list` variable.

Offtopic: `list` is key word in python interpreter, pls don't use variable named like function `list()` in your code. I think it provokes 'minus' votes on you.

@EDIT:
At first, change variable name `list` for `array`.
Then, it should work:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    txtchan = client.get_channel(int(chan))
    while not client.is_closed():
        message = ''.join(random.sample(array, 3))
        await txtchan.send(message)
    client.run(token, bot=False)
```

If it won't work, and some error occured, send it to us. Without that, most of people there, can't easy and fast test it and tell you what wasn't correct.

And i hope it isn't your all what code contains, becouse it isn't enough to correctly login bot into discord ;)

Comment: the shuffle is work but for repetition its keep sending same emoji

Comment: Yea, becouse u should shuffle before useing it next time, for example use it as function:`>>> def foo(arr):
...     random.shuffle(arr)
...     return arr[:3]
... 
>>> a
[3, 6, 0, 5, 4, 9, 1, 2, 7, 8]
>>> foo(a)
[2, 4, 9]
>>> a
[2, 4, 9, 7, 5, 6, 8, 3, 0, 1]
>>> foo(a)
[8, 2, 3]
` But you still will always got shuffled 'a', when you don't use copy.

Comment: can you check my question,  i got some script from friend but it cant worked maybe u can see it

Comment: I already editted, maybe it should work, but read it, with commentaries, not only copy/paste, becouse u occure an error

Comment: Its working!, thanks alot for all the help Guaz, Hope u still healthy to helping people

Answer (score 2):

The correct code for this will be

```
text = random.sample(list, 3)
```

This will randomly sample 3 emojis. Change the number to how many samples you want to draw.

Comment: it does prevent repetition. Every time you run this code, the output will not contain repetition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
import random

l = [*range(100)]
choices = random.choices(l, k=3)
print(choices)
```

**Upd.**

Sorry, I've missed that fact, that you need to pick unique values. For that you can use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
choices = random.sample(l, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generator that yields from a `random.sample` in a loop. Every time it's used up all of the sample the loop will continue and make a new sample. Then use `itertools.slice` to grab however many you want for as long as you want.

```
from itertools import islice
import random

def ran(l):
    while True:
        yield from random.sample(l, len(l))

l  = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

randIter = ran(l)
for i in range(20):
    print(list(islice(randIter, 7))) # pull off 7 at a time to make it easy to verify:
```

**Result**

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

This uses all 14 in random order before repeating and each repeat gets a new order.